# C# SendKeys to Application

Tags: c#, .net

```
public void Press(Keys key)
{
    WindowsAPI.PostMessage(this.Handle, 260u, new UIntPtr((uint)key), UIntPtr.Zero);
}

public void Release(Keys key)
{
    WindowsAPI.PostMessage(this.Handle, 261u, new UIntPtr((uint)key), UIntPtr.Zero);
}

public void gepardkey(Keys key)
{
    this.Press(key);
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    this.Release(key);
}

private void ragnarokgepard_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool flag2 = this.currentHP / this.maxHP *100.0<Convert.ToDouble(this.numHPPercent);
    if (flag2)
    {
        this._windowsAPI.gepardkey(Keys.F1);
    }

    bool flag3 = this.currentSP / this.maxSP *100.0<Convert.ToDouble(this.numSPPercent);
    if (flag3)
    {
        this._windowsAPI.gepardkey(Keys.F2);
    }
}
```

I got this  error http://prntscr.com/lsel0z someone can help me? 
I already use timer and `private void autopots()` but this error still popping

this trainer for ragnarok privateserver

Comment: It is hard to tell from the little information available, you might have to debug "ragnarokgepard_ProgressChanged" and check if any of the variables has an null value. Could you pls add the exception as string in Question, may be that can help in guiding you better

Comment: Can i  get your contact so i can show full source code.

Comment: Post the full exception text instead of picture. The picture is of no use here.

Comment: this.Handle is the handle of application you want to send the key  is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know how you have defined the PostMessage API
but here my definition:

```
const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;//256
const UInt32 WM_KEYDUP = 0x0101;//257
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

and the syntax for keydown for example:(key is virtual key)

```
    WindowsAPI.PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)key, 0);
```

you are using 260 for value of Keydown and 261 for Keyup.....!!??

Answer (score 0):

`this._windowsAPI` is null. Make sure that it's initialized in the constructor or when it's declared.

I assume that you've copied the `gepardkey` method from the WindowsAPI class. If you didn't copy it and it's in the same class as the `ragnarokgepard_ProgressChanged` method then you can replace the the `ragnarokgepard_ProgressChanged` method with this one:

```
private void ragnarokgepard_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool flag2 = this.currentHP / this.maxHP *100.0<Convert.ToDouble(this.numHPPercent);
    if (flag2)
    {
        gepardkey(Keys.F1);
    }

    bool flag3 = this.currentSP / this.maxSP *100.0<Convert.ToDouble(this.numSPPercent);
    if (flag3)
    {
        gepardkey(Keys.F2);
    }
}
```

Comment: its not sending keys :<

Comment: can we talk in  twitter?

Comment: AFAIK it's against the rules. Post your code in a public github repository or a gist and I will correct it.

Comment: This works to send inputs to notepad. https://github.com/paulcsiki/sdfasdf/commit/6aa03b8b08fe5c9bb846e60c5e665efa53de9fd6 Use Spy++ to get the class of the window you want to send messages and don't forget to change the process name back to the original.

Comment: Additionally as Frenchy pointed out your message types were incorrect. Good catch Frenchy!